# Cassandra, Jersey rest api increases Threads, Memory usage and Ports with each rest request

Tags: java, rest, cassandra, jersey

I've created simple jersey rest api to query cassandra. Ajax Long polling is also used. But with each requests memory, ports usage and threads increases even after request completion these do not decreases. closed the cassandra session also but no luck. Below is the rest code

```
@Path("/pull")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONArray get(@QueryParam("offset") String offset, @QueryParam("currentUser") String currentUser,
        @QueryParam("longPolling") boolean longPolling) {
    JSONArray messages = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject message = null;
    Session session = Connector.getSession();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM messages";
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    BoundStatement stmt = null;
    int timeOut = 0;
    try {
        while (messages.length() == 0 && timeOut++ < 30) {
            if (longPolling && !offset.equals("0")) {
                query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id > ? ALLOW FILTERING";
                ps = session.prepare(query);
                stmt = ps.bind(UUID.fromString(offset));
                resultSet = session.execute(stmt);
            } else {
                resultSet = session.execute(query);
            }
            List<Row> ls = resultSet.all();
            ls.sort(new Sort<Row>());
            for (Row row : ls) {
                if ((!longPolling || !row.getString("sentby").equals(currentUser))) {
                    message = new JSONObject();
                    message.put("id", row.getUUID("id"));
                    message.put("sentby", row.getString("sentby"));
                    message.put("message", row.getString("message"));
                    messages.put(message);
                }
            }
            if (messages.length() == 0 && longPolling) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        message = null;
        resultSet = null;
        session.close();
    }
    return messages;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you are initialising session and tearing it down every time. Session is a relatively heavy object and only one should be used per application. Please put the session to some other bean and then use dependency injection in your code here to get it. Don't open and close session per request. This will definitely not be performant.

Also don't prepare the statements every time. On this bean of yours create one prepared statement only and use it across requests.

Comment: Yes you are right.. not closing session did the work. Also prepared statement once and is giving more boost to the performance. Thanks!!